# MVC Web.Debug.Config Question Concerning Debug Mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config

This is probably a quick question.  I'm very new to solution configurations and web.config xml file transformations.  I wanted to add a transformation to set the debug attribute for the compilation element of an Asp.Net Mvc website to true:

Web.Debug.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
```

Web.config:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
         ...
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

but when I press F5, a window pops up in Visual Studio saying "The page cannot be run in debug mode because debugging is not enabled in the web.config file."  It then gives me the option to alter the Web.config file.  But I thought the point of the Web.Debug.config file was to allow this to get set automatically...  Can I get Visual Studio to use the transformed Web.config file after pressing F5?

Many thanks in advance!

Andrew

Comment: The web.debug.config is not read by asp.net unless you have add it to the web.config. So set the debug=true on the web.config, and not on web.debug.config.

Comment: @Aristos:  Thanks for the response:)  I think the transformation is working, but it's being output to the debug directory instead of being used for debugging when I press F5...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience, Transformations do not happen when using the F5 or visual studio debugger. It only does transformations after you publish the website.

Comment: can we not achieve that using visual studio extension?? like: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, I've decided to use the following setup instead:

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    ...
  <system.web>    
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
          ...
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Web.Release.config:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

This should cause the compilation debug attribute to get overwritten with "false" when the build deployment configuration is set to "release".

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
< compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2013 if you only have a web.config file, you can right click it and choose "Add Config Transform". By default it contains the

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

which removes the debug="true".